# Efficiently restoring one database to another using AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have a MySQL database called `latest`, and another database called `previous`, both running on the same server. Both databases have identical content. Once per day, an application runs that updates `latest`. Later on, towards the end of the applications execution, a comparison is made between `latest` and `previous` for certain data. Differences that are found, if any, will trigger certain actions e.g. notification emails to sent. After that, a copy of `latest` is dumped to a file using `mysqldump` and restored to `previous`. Both databases are now in sync again and the process repeats the following day.

I would like to migrate the database(s) to AWS RDS. I'm open to using Aurora, but the MySQL engine is fine too. Is there a simpler or more efficient way of performing the *restore* process so that both databases are in sync using RDS? A way that avoids having to use `mysqldump` and feeding the result into `previous`?

I understand that I could create a read replica of an instance running `latest` to act as `previous`, but I think that updates the read replica as the source DB is updated (well, asynchronously anyway) which would ruin the possibility of performing a comparison between the two later on.

I don't have any particular problem with using `mysqldump` for the restore process, but I'm just not sure If I'm missing a trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a read replica, your option using mysqldump is good but probably you could use it with mysqlimport as suggested in the MySQL Docs:

[Copying MySQL Databases to Another Machine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/copying-databases.html)

> You can also use mysqldump and mysqlimport to transfer the database. For large tables, this is much faster than simply using mysqldump.